# How to open a project from geany command line

Tags: geany

I want to open an existing project when I invoke `geany` at command line. It seems to be an obvious need, but I don't see any command line option that allow that.

Somebody knows?

Answer (score 3):

To open a `geany` project from command line, simply give the project file as argument, e.g.

```
geany ~/projects/my_project.geany
```

Answer (score 0):

After initially saving the project from within geany, all you need to do is put the directory name after the geany command. For example, the following is a directory listing with the geany project 'test' saved to it. (notice the test.geany file):

```
lenovo:davidj ~/projects >  ls
test  test.geany
```

To open the the 'test' project on the commandline, do the following:

```
lenovo:davidj ~/projects > geany test
```

Comment: I store all geany project files under a single directory, and I have many projects in various directories. In this case, your answer does not work. But I realize that I have to simply give the project file as argument to geany, I never thought to do that! Thanks anyway.